# Application Program Interface Plumbing code

Tags: api

What is plumbing code in software terminology/API terminology?

I have learnt that SOAP protocol requires less plumbing code than REST and I did not understand what that meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plumbing code is the code that connects API to the data the API is meant to serve.  For example, you may have a GET API that requests a list of movies.  That list of movies is stored in the database.  The code that will fetch the movies from the database and format it in a way that the API specifies is effectively plumbing code.